# Python parse similar arguments for two sections

Tags: python-2.7, argparse

How do I accomplish the following with argparse --

```
python program.py src --ip '10.0.1.100' --key '~/path/to/key' dest --ip '10.0.2.100' --key '~/path/to/key'
```

I've looked at subparsers and I can't quite get it to divide it up like this.

Comment: Argparse only accepts one subparser at a time.

Comment: How about this input: `python program.py --src '10.0.1.100'  '~/path/to/key' --dest '10.0.2.100'  '~/path/to/key'`?  That is, 2 defined actions with `nargs=2` each.

Comment: The problem is I have many src and destination parameters to be passed. The above is just an example for two of them.

So doing `--src 1...6 --dest 1..6` isn't too user friendly or readable.

Comment: Then write your own parser.  What you want doesn't fit with `argparse`.